# Accesing personal Web server remotely

Tags: node.js, web-services, sockets, server

I'm using this project for home automation.
https://ni-c.github.io/heimcontrol.js/

Now i want this server to be able to accessible through web. But the Ip is dynamic, even after port forwarding  ip will keep on changing.
One solution is static IP, but i want some other solution.

thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please see http://www.dnsdynamic.org/

Comment: Networking administration questions will be better received on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

http://dyn.com/dns/

I used this a few years ago for a while. worked well.